# Having issues with UPDATE command

Tags: sql

Using this SP I keep getting an error on the UPDATE statement indicating that I have conversion problem or something. But ID is an integer in all of my tables....

Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'UPDATE tblLangenUS SET [lang_String] = ' -  asdfgsdfg', [prev_LangString] = ' ', [needsTranslation] = 'false' WHERE [ID] = '' to data type int.

```
    @currTable varchar(100),
    @ID int,
    @short_Text varchar(250),
    @brief_Descrip varchar(250) = Null,
    @needsTranslation varchar(10) = Null,
    @prev_LangString varchar(250) = Null,
    @lang_String varchar(250) = Null,
    @original_lang_String varchar(250) = Null,
    @StringID_from_Master varchar(250),     
    @GUID varchar(250) = Null

/*
```

*/

```
AS        
SET NOCOUNT ON;

DECLARE @userTable AS VARCHAR(200);
SET @userTable = @currTable
DECLARE @submitDate1 DATETIME;
SET @submitDate1 = GETDATE()



SET @prev_LangString = @original_lang_String
SET @needsTranslation = 'false'

DECLARE @sql varchar(max)
    -- Establish update to the language tabel of user and prepare to search DB for all strings that will need to be updated.
BEGIN

   SET @sql = 'UPDATE ' + @currTable + ' SET [lang_String] = ''' + @lang_String + ''', [prev_LangString] = ''' + @prev_LangString + ''', [needsTranslation] = ''' + @needsTranslation + ''' WHERE [ID] = ''' + @ID + '''; ' 
   EXEC @sql
   @sql = ''



END

BEGIN               
    DECLARE usedIN_DBScursor CURSOR
    FOR
    SELECT       tblUniquetblStringsMaster_ID, Database_Name, dbKeyID_ofStringName
    FROM         tblDBUsage
    WHERE        (tblUniquetblStringsMaster_ID = @StringID_from_Master );


                -- Declare the variables to store the values returned by FETCH.
    DECLARE @tblUniquetblStringsMaster_ID AS INT;
    DECLARE @dbKEYID as INT;
    DECLARE @dbName as varchar(100);

    OPEN usedIN_DBScursor;

    -- Perform the first fetch and store the values in variables.
    -- Note: The variables are in the same order as the columns
    -- in the SELECT statement. 

    FETCH NEXT FROM usedIN_DBScursor
    INTO @tblUniquetblStringsMaster_ID, @dbName, @dbKEYID;

    -- Check @@FETCH_STATUS to see if there are any more rows to fetch.
    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN
    -- Update pending strings table with translation.           
        BEGIN
            INSERT INTO tblPendingDBUpdates
                                     (stringMasterID, databaseName, databaseStringID, englishText, foreignLangText, submitDate, GUID)
            VALUES        (@StringID_from_Master, @dbName, @dbKEYID, @short_Text, @lang_String, @submitDate1, @GUID);                                       
        END 
--      SET @sql = ''
    -- This is executed as long as the previous fetch succeeds.
        FETCH NEXT FROM usedIN_DBScursor
        INTO @tblUniquetblStringsMaster_ID, @dbName, @dbKEYID;
    END

    CLOSE usedIN_DBScursor;
    DEALLOCATE usedIN_DBScursor;    

END 



RETURN
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the ID is an `int`, you must `CAST` it to an `nvarchar`

```
SET @sql = 'UPDATE ' + @currTable + ' SET [lang_String] = ''' + @lang_String + ''', [prev_LangString] = ''' + @prev_LangString + ''', [needsTranslation] = ''' + @needsTranslation + ''' WHERE [ID] = ''' + CAST(@ID as nvarchar(10)) + '''; '
```

Otherwise, you are trying to add a string and an integer together, which won't work.

Notice this part:

```
   ' WHERE [ID] = ''' + CAST(@ID as nvarchar(10)) + '''
```

I think you must also change your EXEC syntax to:

```
EXEC(@sql)
```

Comment: I've changed your code and added it in my answer. The end of the `SET @sql ...` line shows my change

Comment: With addition of the CAST I get this error. And I am postive that the value of 2 is a valid key value....   The name 'UPDATE tblLangenUS SET [lang_String] = ' -  test this', [prev_LangString] = ' ', [needsTranslation] = 'false' WHERE [ID] = '2'; ' is not a valid identifier.

Comment: Note also that now my Cursor code is not executing. I will try changing the EXEC now.

Comment: I am still having one issue with a date conversion...Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.  Could you help with that?  I added a date variable to the UPDAET statement and get that error.

Comment: It could be that your date format is incorrect perhaps?. Ie. 31/07/2011 isnt the same as 07/31/2011.

Comment: All set found the convert command and now have it working.            , [date_Changed] = ''' +  convert(varchar(20), @submitDate1) + ''',